# Why can't we just call new Activity()

Tags: android, android-activity

So, kind of a noob situation, but today, out of curiosity, I tried to do something like:

`new Activity().runOnUiThread( new Runnable{...})`

mostly because i don't actually have access to any activities (working on a 3rd party library). I just have the applicationContext, which i don't think allows me to make that `runOnUiThread` call.

So i guess i'm kind of wondering if there is a way to somehow fake out a minimally-invasive activity just so i can run something on the UI thread (or do other things, like pop up dialog...etc.) ??

if not, does anyone know what's wrong with just making `new Activity()` ?   ( i mean, aside from the fact that, yes, i will get a null pointer because i haven't set my base context since the `onCreate` for the activity never got called ). if possible, i would like to accept an answer that can provide a little more detail and more "context" (no pun intended)

Comment: Can you give us the method signature for the code you've provided? It'd be very helpful if we know what's passed into your method.

Comment: as you're developing a library, it should means there must be a calling made from the app itself to your library isn't it? why not you just accept a Context object as your function parameter and that should fix all your problem?

Comment: you're right - it's more of a legacy in the design: i didn't ask for a context before, so it'd be awkward in a non-major new version to suddenly ask for a context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new Handler(context.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
    }
});
```

Comment: nice! i forgot about handlers. Do you know how it would work with popping up a dialog though? that `context` you provided is presumably `getApplicationContext()`, which in my code is available via a View. The reason i did `new Activity()` is so that i can later do `... = new AlertDialog.Builder(new Activity());`

Comment: Sorry, can't say: it would be faster for you to run the code. Actually if you have a View instance you can run the code on UI thread using View's method "post".

Answer (score 1):

Activity is managed by Android OS and is not meant to be used this way, to do so would mean breaking the API contract so don't expect it to behave correctly.

If you want to show some dialog, just create an Activity with transparent background, to the user it would be the same as a single Dialog floating above another screen.

Comment: sort of. good suggestion, but that would also put their activity in the background though, whereas they may not have expected a `onPause` event

Comment: Any good behaving Android app should expect onPause at any given time ;)

Comment: i totally agree, and if i were building the application, i would account for it. but this time around i'm building a library and can't assume anything :'(

Comment: For a library another method is to provide integration hooks for integrating apps to call. For example, integrating lib can call into your lib to check if your lib can handle the particular onCreateDialog event, etc.

Comment: True, you have a good solution and it normally, i just mucked it up from the beginning. (can't expect people to adapt to a new library just because i messed up) Thanks though.